# Eliminar archivos especificos mediante el nombre con un .BAT

Tags: script, batch, consola

Necesito crear un archivo .bat en modo silencioso

que elimine archivos especificos poninedo el nombre y su extencion
para que no elimine los demas archivos que se encuentran en la misma carpeta con la misma extencion

ejemplo de los archivos que quiero eliminar al mismo tiempo:

C:\carpeta1\Nuevacarpeta  **archivo.json**

C:\carpeta1\Nuevacarpeta  **data.sqlite**

C:\carpeta1\Nuevacarpeta  **archivo.txt**

Answer (score 1):

Hazlo con `del /q`. Con `del` borras y con el parámetro `/q` lo haces sin emitir ningún mensaje. Así:

```
del /q archivo.json
```